# How to display ad hoc constraints form validation messages?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

## ScalaForms

In the example linked [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaForms) there is this example about form validation:

```
// You can also define ad-hoc constraints on the fields:
val loginForm = Form(
  tuple(
    "email" -> nonEmptyText,
    "password" -> text
  ) verifying("Invalid user name or password", fields => fields match { 
      case (e, p) => User.authenticate(e,p).isDefined 
  })
)
```

Via binding errors some constraints are displayed in my form. (Like the `nonEmptyText`, that gets a extra line behind the field stating `This field is required`. See:

```
loginForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
  formWithErrors => // binding failure, you retrieve the form containing errors,
  value => // binding success, you get the actual value 
)
```

If I do a `.toString` to the `formWithErrors` i get this for the `nonEmptyText` constraint:

```
Form(ObjectMapping2(<function2>,<function1>,(Email adress,FieldMapping(,List(Constraint(Some(constraint.required),WrappedArray())))),(Password,FieldMapping(,List(Constraint(Some(constraint.required),WrappedArray())))),,List(Constraint(None,List()))),Map(Password -> test, Email adress -> ),List(FormError(Email adress,error.required,WrappedArray())),None)
```

The latter part is a [FormError](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/data/FormError.html) List: `List(FormError(Email adress,error.required,WrappedArray())),None)` which is a case class: `case class FormError (key: String, message: String, args: Seq[Any])` where `key` is defined as: `The error key (should be associated with a field using the same key).`.

The FieldConstructor picks this up and makes the 'Email adress' input box go red and add the error message ('This field is required').

### Displaying the ad hoc constraints?

So when the form fields are all filled the username and password are checked:

```
verifying("Invalid user name or password", fields => fields match { 
      case (e, p) => User.authenticate(e,p).isDefined 
  })
```

But i dont know how to display the 'Invalid user name or password' to the user. The `.toString` of the `FormError` List of `formWithErrors` is:

```
List(FormError(,Invalid user name or password,WrappedArray())),None)
```

The `Key` part is empty.

### Question

How do i display the ad hoc error?

I even tried:

```
BadRequest( views.html.test( formWithErrors ) ).flashing( "error" -> "Invalid user name or password." ) },
```

but for some reason its not working via the Flash either :(. This `@flash.get("error").getOrElse("no 'error'")` gives me 'no error' each time.

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to get the key to show up in the errors? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, a form can have `errors` attached to it, so then when a bind from request fails validating constraint, a new form is created based on the given one, but filled in with `errors`.

Such errors list is composed of  `FormError` which refers a Form Field and overrides toString to show its embed message.

This way if you wish to show all messages at once, you can simply `formWithErrors.errors.mkString("<br>")` for instance (in you template or flashing it).

There are a lot of ways and some common ones are described here http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaFormHelpers. You might define your own field constructor as well.

To conclude, my advice would be that you should use helpers amap (for instance `@inputText` and <sup>co</sup>) because they already contain the logic to show helpers, tips and **errors** when available.

### Edit

I missed the hint about the flash problem... you've probably forgotten to add `(implicit flash: Flash)` to you template param list. (don't forget to flag the request as implicit as well in your action definition)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Though its not what i'm looking for i think. Here is why: i am using FormHelpers, even added my own for bootstrap (but disabled it to test it). The ad hoc error isnt on 1 Field, its on a combination. (Hence the helpers not showing the error.)
The tip for '@formWithErrors.errors.toString' in my template was helpful. As i indeed do see the error in there. (Albeit its a list of multiple errors.)
I think the key is in the fact the 'Key' is empty. I'll use your '.errors' and some logic to filter out the 'general' error message.

Any idea why my @flash isnt picking it up?

Comment: no p. What you could done as well it to filter out all error message related to empty Key like that `formWithErrors.errors.filter(_.key == "")`. It gives you a seq of form error (which should be a singleton). And it'll be the errors for the top level.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The filter tip is nice, i'll use that. The edit (for the flash): i did add that. The flash is otherwise working because lines like this (to the same page) shows me the flash message: `Redirect( routes.UserManagement.login ).withNewSession.flashing("success" -> "You are now logged out." )` <-- works. I just noticed that in the question i use `views.html.test( formWithErrors )` and the quoted working line above uses the reverse route. Could that be a reason why it's not picking up the flash?

Comment: Hmmm should working like that too... Maybe could you try with another key than error... 'd be strange but still.